# Python3: os.system not redirecting stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, os.system

As mentioned in the title. I have this in my code:

```
os.system("./vpr/vpr " + config + " " + file_name + " --seed " + str(seed) + " &> " + str(bench_name) + "-" + str(seed) + ".stdout")
```

Which has a lot of variables, but it simply evaluates to this (I know for sure because I have a print statement right before the `os.system` line):

```
./vpr/vpr vpr/k6_N10_40nm.xml vpr/blif/clma.blif --seed 0 &> clma-0.stdout
```

The command actually runs fine, but the redirection does not! The file `clma-0.stdout` gets created but remains empty, and I still get the entire stdout on my terminal.

What is the solution for that? What am I doing wrong?
I'm using python-3.7 on Ubuntu 19.10

Thanks.

Comment: @DYZ actually it redirects both stdout and stderr to the file.

Comment: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Beside the point, but why is the file called `.stdout` if you're redirecting stdout *and* stderr to it?

Comment: It's because the vpr program doesn't actually use stderr. And I have this habit of redirecting both anyway to the same file.

No good reasons, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's because you are trying to do it using system command, not Bash which supports these I/O redirection flags.

Try this one with `shell=True` https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why exactly, but it seems like `os.system` is using Dash (Ubuntu's default scripting shell), not Bash, so `&>` is not supported. What happens instead is the command is backgrounded, and the file is truncated. That is, `command &> filename` is equivalent to `command &; > filename`.

To fix it you could simply use the equivalent redirection, `> filename 2>&1`.